# Ajax file upload - Error on server side

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, html

I am trying to implement ajax file upload via the HTML5 File API. It's based on Afzaal Ahmad Zeeshan's answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery) question.

I've basically copied the entire code that he wrote, but can't get it to work.

The main aim here is to be able to upload `.xls` and `.xlsx` files to the server to work with them later with `PHPExcel`.

Here's my HTML:

```
<form class="form-uploadXLS" method="post" action="php/uploadXLS.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <input type="file" name="xls" class="xls" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="button" value="Upload" class="btn-uploadXLS" />
</form>
<progress></progress>
```

And here are the jQuery event handlers, just like in the above mentioned answer:

File input `onChange` event:

```
$('.xls').on('change', function () {
    var file = this.files[0];
    var fileName = file.name;
    var fileType = file.type;
    var fileSize = file.size;

    console.log("file name: " + fileName + ", type: " + fileType + ", size: " + fileSize);
});
```

Upload button's `onClick` event:

```
$('.btn-uploadXLS').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("Upload button clicked");
    var formData = new FormData($('.form-uploadXLS')[0]);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'php/uploadXLS.php', //Server script to process data
        type: 'POST',
        xhr: function () { // Custom XMLHttpRequest
            var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
            if (myXhr.upload) { // Check if upload property exists
                myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', progressHandlingFunction, false); // For handling the progress of the upload
            }
            return myXhr;
        },
        //Ajax events
        beforeSend: function (stuff) {
            console.log("BeforeSend");
            console.log(stuff);
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("Success!");
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log("Error!");
            console.log(error);
        },
        // Form data
        data: formData,
        //Options to tell jQuery not to process data or worry about content-type.
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });
});
```

**Edit starts here:**

And finally here's my PHP code that prints out the $_FILES array:

```
if(!empty($_FILES['xls'])) {
    echo '<pre>',print_r($_FILES,1),'</pre>';
}
else {
    die('POST ÜRES');
}
```

And here's the result:

```
Array
(
    [xls] => Array
        (
            [name] => 
            [type] => 
            [tmp_name] => 
            [error] => 4
            [size] => 0
        )

)
```

For some reason I can't access the error messages, it only contains the number 4.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For files  you need

`$_FILES['xls']` not `$_POST`

Read [Handling file uploads](https://www.php.net/features.file-upload)

---

To get more info just print array

```
echo '<pre>',print_r($_FILES,1),'</pre>'
```

Read [php - file upload](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php)

[Ajax File Upload with PHP, HTML5 File API and jQuery](http://www.sanwebe.com/2012/06/ajax-file-upload-with-php-and-jquery)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Now the $_FILES['xls'] variable is not empty, but I get errors. I edited the question.